# How do I install Ubuntu on to a blank laptop

Tags: laptop

I downloaded Ubuntu to one laptop and burned it to a blank dvd. Then I put the CD to the blank laptop on start up and nothing happens. There was no Windows image disc burner software on the laptop. What do I do? Thanks.

Comment: Have you tried downloading another ISO and burning into a different DVD or CD?

Answer (score 2):

Check your BIOS settings and make sure it's booting from the CD-ROM. You can check your BIOS settings by pressing <kbd>F2</kbd>, <kbd>F10</kbd>, or <kbd>F12</kbd> it should show which button to press to getting into your BIOS settings on the screen on boot up.

Comment: Tried each of those buttons, nothing shows. Each key I press sounds a loud beep.

Answer (score 2):

Two things are important to clarify here. 
1. Have you burned the CD with "boot CD" options ?
2. Have you changed the boot priority of your system to CD-ROM in BIOS settings ?

And since you are asking question about installation mention the version of the system (laptop) and the motherboard that your system configured with.

But here is your answer if you have burned your CD with Boot option.
Generally to get into BIOS settings f2 or del will be the key. If both of them doesn't work for you, check on-line to know your bios key. Then set boot priority to CD-Rom, save and exit. Now insert your CD and reboot your system it will start from Ubuntu.

**Note** : Since you have not yet installed the os, take this advice. Create a partition of about twice or equal to your RAM size and assign it for swapping purpose(You will see this option while installing). It is required for hibernation purpose which you are going to use definitely.

**Update : Burning CD with Bootable option using Nero:** Follow instructions in this link "path=Blog%3A%2F%2FDisplayBlogComposite%2FNero%2F7419946&NCSS=a105m2ZYu9KFk6jZd0ce28lWPpMvvNt5fffd#0">http://my.nero.com/index.php?_path=Blog%3A%2F%2FDisplayBlogComposite%2FNero%2F7419946&NCSS=a105m2ZYu9KFk6jZd0ce28lWPpMvvNt5fffd#0"

1. To go to bios settings turn on and press immediately esc button and then(one second later) f2 button for setup f12 button for boot setup. i.e esc and f2 or esc and f12. Look for option boot and set boot priority as mentioned before.

Comment: It's a Toshiba Satellite and it has zero OS on it. When I turn it on I just get a blank screen with a blinking cursor in the top left corner. I've tried tapping esc, f2, f10 and f12 and nothing happens. Even tried the delete button and still nothing to get the BIOS up. Go easy on me, I'm a layman with little experience. When I burned the program to DVD I simply used a burn program I already had 'Power2Go' and burned it normally. How do I do the boot CD option?

Comment: you have to press those keys before you reach the blank screen with blinking cursor

Comment: Ok so I finally got the laptop to go to the BIOS screen. However I don't think the disc I burned was a bootable version. I'm trying to make a boot disc but for some reason I can't get the program to pick up Ubuntu as an image. What gives?

Comment: I hope you have iso image file. If so, using powerISO extract all the files to a known location or mount the image file. Then follow these steps "http://www.poweriso.com/tutorials/make-bootable-cd.htm"